# Why do checkPermission and has_permission return different results?

Tags: plone

Why do:

```
user.has_permission(permission, object)
```

and

```
user.checkPermission(permission, object)
```

return different results?

checkPermission seems to be the correct result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because they are **different functions**.

`has_permission` is a method of the `BasicUser` class in `AccessControl/users.py`:

```
def has_permission(self, permission, object):
    """Check if the user has a permission on an object.

    This method is just for inspecting permission settings. For access
    control use getSecurityManager().checkPermission() instead.
    """
    roles=rolesForPermissionOn(permission, object)
    if isinstance(roles, str):
        roles=[roles]
    return self.allowed(object, roles)
```

while `checkPermission` is a function defined in `AccessControl/security.py`:

```
def checkPermission(permission, object, interaction=None):
    """Return whether security policy allows permission on object.

    Arguments:
    permission -- A permission name
    object -- The object being accessed according to the permission
    interaction -- This zope.security concept has no equivalent in Zope 2,
        and is ignored.

    checkPermission is guaranteed to return True if permission is
    CheckerPublic or None.
    """
    if (permission in ('zope.Public', 'zope2.Public') or
        permission is None or permission is CheckerPublic):
        return True

    if isinstance(permission, basestring):
        permission = queryUtility(IPermission, unicode(permission))
        if permission is None:
            return False

    if getSecurityManager().checkPermission(permission.title, object):
        return True

    return False
```

`has_permission` is used for inspecting permission settings while `checkPermission` is used for access control. In other words, **a user may *not* have permission settings on an object but still have access** via some other security policy mechanism.

Comment: Can you provide an example of a user not having permission settings on an object but still having access via some other security policy mechanism? I thought permissions were the one and only security policy mechanism.

Comment: E.g. user aclark is a member of group Ploners who have the Read permission on the folder PloneStuff. aclark.has_permission(Read, PloneStuff) fails because the user does not have explicit Read permission (i.e. Read is not give to user aclark on that object) but aclark.checkPermission(Read, PloneStuff) succeeds because aclark is a member of the group Ploners. This is untested, but how I imagine such an example would work.